# JConsole not connecting to java process

Tags: java, jconsole, jvisualvm

When I start `JConsole` it identifies my  java process(local) but it is not able to connect to it.

```
Connection Failed: Retry?
The connection to 17424 did not succeed.
Would you like to try again?
```

Selecting connect again gives the same error(17424 is the pid of the java process).On the other hand  `jvisualvm` works perfectly. In jvisualvm I see the following details

```
PID: 17424
Host: localhost
Main class: Conatainer

JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.6-b04, mixed mode)
Java: version 1.7.0_11, vendor Oracle Corporation
Java Home: /home/aniket/jdk1.7.0_11/jre
JVM Flags: <none>
```

Has anyone encountered this situation before? Is it a bug? Is there a work around?

Comment: I have the same in ubuntu. No solution found until now. (But I didn't try hard.)

Answer (score 5):

You may be running JVisualVM as a different user than the user running the Java application.  Make sure you're running as the same user or as a super user.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the answer on the manual .

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html

> Under previous releases of the Java SE platform, to allow the JMX client access to a local Java VM, you had to set the following system property when you started the Java VM or Java application.
>
> com.sun.management.jmxremote

Comment: Please paste the content of the link as answer. Thanks